# Save "backup copy" of workbook without committing changes to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, file, save, backup

I'm not sure this is possible but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I want to programmatically, and invisibly save a "backup" copy of the workbook in it's current state, without "committing" the changes to Excel or destroying the *Undo* history.

### Example Scenario:

1. User opens `c:\folder1\workbookA.xlsm`
2. User makes changes to the workbook that *they may not wish to commit to*.
3. My sub begins due to timer or other event, and in the background, saves a copy of the workbook as `c:\folder2\workbookB.xlsm`

The catch is that this the action of creating a backup copy needs to be "invisible" to the user, so that if they later `Save` **or** `close discarding changes`, the result will be the same as if my backup copy was not created.

**This means:**

- the filename in the **titlebar** has not changed,
- Ctrl+Z/**Undo** still works,
- if the user **closes** the workbook, they are still prompted to <kbd>Save Changes?</kbd>
  (easy with [`workbook.Saved = False`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saved-property-excel))

  - if they choose <kbd>Yes</kbd> then the workbook is saved like normal
    (replacing the file at `c:\folder1\workbookA.xlsm`.)
  - if they choose <kbd>No</kbd>, the workbook is closed and the file at `c:\folder1\workbookA.xlsm` is still in it's original, unmodified form, **as if no changes were made** in Step #2.

As far as I know, [`workbook.SaveAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel) always updates the name of the workbook and clears the "undo" history, so there's no way to close the file without keeping changes.
Thanks!

Comment: I guess the only way is to create new workbook, copy worksheets, save it and close.

Comment: @omegastripes That's what I was trying to avoid... but "worst case"...

Comment: Does the built in auto save not do it for you?

Comment: @chrisneilsen - That would be nice, but the built-in AutoSave doesn't work for locally saved files in Excel 2016; it's intended for files saved on OneDrive.  That's basically what I'm trying to replicate.  The AutoRecover is a joke too, giving users a false sense of security, as far as I'm concerned.  Both my client and myself have lost a lot of work over the months due to Excel closing unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was sitting there thinking, *"if only there was a **Save Copy As…** option..."*

Then I realized the solution was right in front of me:  [the `.SaveCopyAs` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-savecopyas-method-excel).

---

> ## Workbook.SaveCopyAs Method (Excel)
>
> Saves a copy of the workbook to a file but **doesn't modify the open workbook in memory.**
>
> ### Syntax
>
> *`expression`* `.` **`SaveCopyAs(` *`Filename`* `)`**
>
> - `expression`  - a variable that represents a `Workbook` object.
> - `Filename` *Variant* (Required) - Specifies the file name for the copy.

<sub>**Note:** The documentation mistakenly says the `Filename` parameter is *optional* (which wouldn't make sense).

      I've [edited](https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/pull/583) the MSDN page, pending approval.</sub>

Comment: And you were so close.... you were thinking there was a **Save Copy As** method and there was only a `SaveCopyAs` method ... ;)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yeah those damn Chr(32)'s get me every time....  [smartass]