# Only save the code

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently learning Excel VBA and since CTRL+Z doesn't undo anything, I'm trying to find a way to undo what my code does when I have to. On my office computer, I can click on the Save button from VBE and it saves my code, but nit the workbook. 
On my personal computer (Office 365), when I do the exact same thing, it saves everything, code and workbook so I cannot undo what my code did by not saving it.

Can you help me to understand why? And do you have any idea I can undo what my code did?

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK You cannot undo the changes made to your sheet after running your code. Create backups instead before running or as first steps within running.

Comment: I realized I can't undo what my code did, but what I'm trying to do is to find a way to save my code without saving my sheets. This way, I can "undo" my code, simply by leaving my workbook without saving it (but saving the code). In brief, saving VBE without saving Excel

Comment: You can export code for example, or even simpler, set up a routine that saves a copy instead (i.e. [SaveCopyAs method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50883884/6241235)).

Comment: Thank you for the SaveCopyAs method. This is not exactly what I am looking for, but it will help. I just don't understand why I Can't save my code and my workbook at different moments.

Comment: Ron de Bruin’s site has a good bit of code that will let you export or import your own code. https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

Comment: If you wanted to “version” your code you can set the file name of those exports to have a time stamp or you could even use git which is what I like to do

Comment: Always use a copy of your workbook to test code. Always save your workbook before you run your code, If your code does not perform the way you expect, then exit your workbook without saving it. When you reopen your workbook your data will be unchanged.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to write code, test it on my workbook, see it doesn't work, save the code and leave the workbook without saving. This way, when I open the file, I have the old workbook with the new book.                                   According to you, it's not possible, but on my Office computer, it's ao easy. Simply hit the Save button in VBE but not touching the Save button of the Workbook. Although, it doesn't work on ny personal computer

Comment: I finally found the reason. I was saving my code in a PERSONAL excel file, which was a different file. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Export code modules to file - either manually by right-clicking on them, or via code (check out VBA Extensibility), or;

2) Do what I do, which is the easy option of just copying chunks of code as text into Notepad.

There doesn’t exist what you’re really looking for: an integral method of “saving” the VBProject but ignoring the workbook - as the VBProject is part of the workbook when it comes to file structure.